# python cgi + a web interface for running batch commands?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, cgi

I'm porting a Python script that runs via command line to Python CGI so I can control the options with HTML form elements. How can I access the results of the commands?

Script currently runs these commands:

- svn update
- rsync copy images from other local folders
- recompile CSS
- svn commit
  *loop these commands over a dozen times

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
  print
  print 'test...'
  os.system("svn update /Users/daverau/titles/or_mm_creating_website_3e")
  ```

How can I access the console output of this command? Is there a better way to setup this kind of local job?

Security isn't a concern, this is a local Mac tool for myself only.

Answer (score 2):

The two good answers pointed you the subprocess module.

There are also few wrappers built around this module that are well worth a look:

#### 1) sh module (former PBS)

[update]
Use PBS if you are stuck with MS Windows, else use its successor, the [sh module](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/).

Using the sh module:

```
from sh import ifconfig, ls
print(ifconfig("eth0"))
print(ls('-la'))
```

Using PBS, from the README at https://github.com/amoffat/pbs:

```
import pbs
print pbs.ifconfig("eth0")
print pbs.ls('-la')
```

#### 2) Plumbum

Detailed information at http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Some examples from the README file:

Basics:

```
>>> from plumbum import local, FG, BG
>>> from plumbum.cmd import ls, grep, wc, cat, head
>>> ls
LocalCommand(<LocalPath /bin/ls>)
>>> ls()
u'build.py\ndist\ndocs\nLICENSE\nplumbum\nREADME.rst\nsetup.py\ntests\ntodo.txt\n'
```

Piping:

```
>>> chain = ls["-a"] | grep["-v", "\\.py"] | wc["-l"]
>>> print chain
/bin/ls -a | /bin/grep -v '\.py' | /usr/bin/wc -l
>>> chain()
u'13\n'
```

Redirection:

```
>>> ((cat < "setup.py") | head["-n", 4])()
u'#!/usr/bin/env python\nimport os\n\ntry:\n'
>>> (ls["-a"] > "file.list")()
u''
>>> (cat["file.list"] | wc["-l"])()
u'17\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use subprocess.call for this use case:

```
from subprocess import call
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print
print 'test...'
response = call(["svn", "update", "/Users/daverau/titles/or_mm_creating_website_3e"])
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted already, a good way to do this is with the subprocess module. The `call` convenience function will allow you to reassign STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR but it is potentially risky because `call` automatically blocks until completion which can create a deadlock if you fill the I/O pipe. I recommend just using `Popen`:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen( ["svn", "update", "/Users/daverau/titles/or_mm_creating_website_3e"], subprocess.PIPE )
out = p.communicate()[0]  # 0 is STDOUT
```

From here you can read the output or manipulate it however you like.